# Android HttpPost: strange behaviour of response

Tags: android, https

```
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutConnection = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URLinString);


        json = jsonObject.toString();
        System.out.println("input json is::" + json);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

This piece of code sometime returning JSON response in string and sometime result is empty, But in either case nature is not predictable.
I am new to android development , Kindly tell me the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to test the service you query data from using another agent ? (Fiddler) How can you be so sure that your is code messing up and not the response from the service?

Comment: Every time on hitting url in browser I am getting proper json as a response . even  String result in my code sometime "" and sometime fetching response.

Comment: Even int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); is returing 200 every time. but  still result="".

Comment: the browser does GET requests, and you are doing a POST. The problem may be in the server side

Comment: @nandsito thanks for your input.But is there any solution for this???

Comment: can you inspect and debug the server?

Comment: @nandsito  Even I have done Get request I am facing same issue.
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalUrl);

Comment: @nandsito Yes the problem is solved now. There was data connection issue at the server.